# Unable to determine IP address from host name

Tags: apache, proxy, dns, osx-lion, squid

We have an iMac running as an internal dev server with Apache, PHP & Mysql.

It has a number of virtual host files and when accessing on the iMac, these work brilliantly.

We're also running Squid proxy server http://web.me.com/adg/squidman/ so that we can access the web through our connection when we're mobile.

General web browsing and such is fine when accessed via proxy, however when we try access a virtualhost url like ourtestsite.dev we get the following message:

> Blockquote
>   he following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://ourtestsite.dev/

```
Unable to determine IP address from host name "ourtestsite.dev"
```

The DNS server returned:

```
Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
```

This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if the address is correct.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.

Can anyone shed any light on how we make these urls accessible via the proxy?

Thanks

Comment: You either need to run your own DNS server, or pass around a /etc/hosts file for everyone to share with the IPs of 'local' boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

within the network config on the iMac, I told it not to use the proxy for addresses that were *.dev

I had this working before with .local addresses but *.local is added as an exception automagically.

So adding the wildcard has solved and we're golden :-)

Comment: What? Can you please describe more?

Answer (score 0):

Just add an entry to the hosts file on your squid server pointing all the virtually hosted domains to the IP address of the iMac. This will bypass DNS lookups for those domains.